# How to handle Recurrent event Survival analysis (Counting Process Approach) in Python

Tags: python, survival-analysis, cox-regression, recurring-events

I am trying to find a way to model Survival Models for Recurrent Events in Python, especially the Counting process approach using CoxPH. In Counting Process Approach, it is expecting start-time and stop-time. But the fit method of CoxPHFitter in lifeline is expecting only a single duration column for time. I could not find any alternative method in Python for handling the same.

Could someone please provide any solution/pointers for handling recurrent events survival analysis in Python.

I am aware of survrec in R, but i need to find a way in python

Thanks in Advance